# ¿Cómo añadir clase CSS a condicional if en WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Cómo puedo hacer para que al llamar la etiqueta "NUEVO", a esta se le aplique una clase CSS en especial y si no está la palabra "NUEVO" no muestre esa el css?.

En terminos concretos es aplicar el css que esta en el código, a la llamada de la tags.

```html
<div <?php if(the_tags('nuevo')) { ?> class="label" <?php } ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es por que falta cerrar tu div ?>>

ejemplo:

```
<div <?php if(the_tags('nuevo')) { ?> class="label" <?php } ?>></div>
```

o

```
<div <?php if(the_tags('nuevo')) {  echo 'class="label"'; } ?>></div>
```

Comment: lo cerré y continua igual

Comment: [codigo]<div nuevo<a="" href="https://www.tengomipagina.cl/tag/nuevo-articulo/" rel="tag">Nuevo Articulo&gt;</div>[codigo]